# Merging related questions that slipped through the duplicate net

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

How do I request the merging of related questions? (I just did, didn't I, but what is the correct way of asking?)

My latest example comes from an Android behaviour which is sometimes [seen as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59645). It affects all types of `View` classes, but has been asked a few times, relating to specific subclasses of View.

- [Does changing the background also change the padding of a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886140/does-changing-the-background-also-change-the-padding-of-a-linearlayout) (May 2010)
- [setBackgroundResource() discards my XML layout attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890379/setbackgroundresource-discards-my-xml-layout-attributes) (May 2011)
- [Where'd padding go, when setting background Drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095196/whered-padding-go-when-setting-background-drawable) (Apr 2012)

As a non-Android developer, these are perhaps not duplicates. However, I view them as duplicates since the underlying issue is the same in each case, the issue lies with their superclass `View` behaviour.

When I [ask the google about this](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=android%20setbackgroundresource%20changes%20padding), I get these 3 links, and I don't see that I would want to discard any of the info.

---

My ideal solution to this would be a way to merge these posts into one, with a comment that they relate to the superclass.

Another way would be to visit all of these posts and create a web of cross links on each one, to each of the others. At least then the system would show them as related. Seems like the wrong solution though, and I've been chastised in the past for similar behaviour.

Or perhaps these are just the most basic of duplicates, needing basic closing - but to me that's not so cut'n'dry.

---

If these are merge candidates, I will happily look for more examples to add to the list.

One day I might hit 20k; by then I hope I've built up enough understanding to not destroy the site with my new-found power.

Comment: If google already serves all three when asking about that issue, is there really a problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Mat I'm more interested in the overall issue of merging, rather than these specifics. The exact specific posts related do not interest me much anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If the questions are really duplicates and vistors of any of those questions would really benefit if they see all answers on both question then a merge is worthwhile.

There is no UI option for us mortals to request a merge. Your only option is to raise a custom flag on the target question, explain which source question(s) should be merged and why you think they should be merged.

As this can be tricky to judge the approach you took here is preferable. So have a meta-post to create the oppertunity for other users to chime in about the proposed merge and verify that there is enough support to do so. Your custom flag can then have a link to the meta post for back-up.